# ServiceStack squirrel

Tags: servicestack

I am using the starter (free) version of ServiceStack to develop an Open Source Windows Service. I have been looking for a means to have the running Windows Service regularly poll a URL for newer versions, and if found, to download the newer version and update the running service. A few hours of searching turns up some commercial products and one open source library for performing auto-updates on general applications, and from Jul 2016, a ServiceStack update post on GitHub which mentions adding auto-update to the ServiceStack React Desktop App via the Squirrel.Windows Open Source library. But nothing turns up directly relating to performing an autoupdate of a Windows Service built on the ServiceStack framework.

Before I start down the path of rolling my own solution, I wanted to ask the ServiceStack community here if there is already a solution that I've overlooked? Especially a solution that leverages Squirrel.Windows, as that library looks to be pretty active at this time

TIA!

Answer (score 1):

ServiceStack doesn't have an auto update solution for Windows Services, just for [Winforms Desktop Apps](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/ReactDesktopApps#02-package-winforms) as part of the [React Desktop Templates](http://docs.servicestack.net/templates-desktop).